# CSS Grid with max number of columns with dynamic children

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simplified version of what I'm trying to do in a project.  The parent can have any number of children as they are pulled from the db.  The children do not have a set width.  I would like to set a max number of columns per row before wrapping and if there are less than that max, the children would widen and fill that space.  As you can see in the example below, when there are only 3 children, there is a gap the size of the 4th child to the right.  How can I accomplish this?

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

.children {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `auto-fit` within the `grid-template-columns` along with a `minmax`, since you have a gap and likely default browser padding, use a calculated width, stretching the children/s width out across the parent row regardless of whether there are enough items in to fill the rows width.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(25% - 1rem), 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  gap: 1em;
}

.children {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>  
</div>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>  
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<br><br>
I have a feeling this is <i><b>NOT</b></i> what you are after... as the last rows columns do not fit to the row.
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>  
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>  
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

There is a caveat though as this will break after the first ***row*** in your grid layout. If you want the continuation of this set column width yet allowing children to spread out over the rows width despite having ample width of children to fit, less than 4 (100% / 4) in this example, then I would suggest using ***`flex`*** for this dynamic layout.

You can simply add a ***min-width*** of the calculated width ***gap + 25%*** and then add `flex-grow: 1;` to the children, while the parent will have `flex-wrap: wrap;` so the elements wrap to the next line and they will also fit their contents width to fill the parents row regardless of their content.

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.parent')

const target = parent[3];

const arr = ['John', 'Bill', 'Bob', 'Karen', 'Joe', 'Debbie', 'Larry', 'Phil', 'Douglas', 'Jason']
arr.forEach(val => {
  let child = document.createElement('DIV')
  child.classList.add('children')
  child.textContent = val
  target.append(child)
})
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

.children {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: calc(25% - 1em);
  background-color: red;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>  
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>  
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
I have a feeling this is what you are after... The last rows columns now fits the rows width despite being a smaller percentage of width needed to fill it. While still stretching the smaller numbers to fill a single row when there are less 4 elements => <i><b>calc(25% - 1em)</b></i>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">1</div>
  <div class="children">2</div>  
  <div class="children">3</div>
  <div class="children">4</div>
  <div class="children">5</div>  
  <div class="children">6</div>  
  <div class="children">7</div>
</div>
<br><br>
Dynamically placed text in layout:
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that last one was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: glad to help 